# How to make new Application Settings in code

Tags: wpf, vb.net, application-settings

I'm learning how to save values to application setting on my vb.net wpf app. But is their a easy way to create new settings in code. Not just change old ones, create new ones. I'm making a note taking program for my employer who is an IT guy who take lots of notes every day. I need to save the notes somewhere. Maybe xml file isn't a good idea just let me know.

Thanks

Comment: If you want to save application settings, here is one way: http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/72654-using-settings/ I have a feeling you may mean you want to save your data (Notes) and are considering saving them to an xml file? If you have "lots of notes" you would probably want to save them to a database. Lot's of good tutorials out there like this one: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LCfvcBObX8k

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used a string listarray stored in application settings.

In your project document you can create a setting and in the "type" option click browse. Type in `System.Collections.ArrayList`in the select type field. Then in the Page.Load event on your main page type the following code

```
If My.Settings.setting1 Is Nothing Then
    My.Settings.setting1 = New ArrayList()
End If
```

And then you can use the array as normally. But I think it is a string array so only strings will work. (correct me if I'm wrong)

Answer (score 2):

If the requirement is to store notes, it would be much easier to use Microsoft [OneNote](http://www.onenote.com/) comes with MS Office. It also has a free version with any Hotmail, live, msn, outlook accounts. If can store 15GB of data. Even you can use it from any device, Windows, iPad, Android etc.

Comment: My employer is picky :) He know about onenote but doesn't like it. He wanted a custom program made.